# How to implmenet the receive-response pattern in custom WCF LOB adapter

Tags: biztalk

So in the TryReceive() method construct the message object and return it to the engine which will be submitted to the message box. My scenario requires the receive-response message exchange pattern, in a way that adapter will send a reply back to the LOB system when the incoming received message is successfully committed to the messaggebox, where should I send the response message?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to be clearer with your questions. We want to help but we cannot read your mind. We need as much technical detail about what is the specific challenge you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to expose some of you application schemas as a WCF service. You can do this by using the WCF Service Publishing Wizard, which you can find in the BizTalk program menu (from All Programs).

If this is the case and you want further guidance then reply to this via a comment and I will expend this answer.

Comment: I think @ninithepug genuinely is trying to build a custom LOB adapter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/bb905478. But agree with your comment re clarity.

Answer (score 0):

WCF LOB Adapter SDK supports this scenario as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb798121%28v=bts.10%29.aspx.

It seems like a combination of Synchronous Inbound and Asynchronous Outbound.